# Hamburger menu has too much line spacing

Tags: html, css

My Hamburger menu has too much spacing below each list element. I just want them to be closley stacked on top of one another.

What is currently looks like (cant see other list elements such as about, shop, contact, news. I want them to be all visible):
https://ibb.co/wcBLz9M

Using only html and css (no css frameworks, js)

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    font-family: montserrat;
}

nav {
    background-color: #0082e6;
    height: 80px;
    width: 100%;
}

.innerheader {
    width: 90%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: red;
}

.logocontainer {
    height: 100%;
    display: table;
    float: left;
}

.logocontainer h1 {
    color: white;
    height: 100%;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-family: "Montserrat";
    font-weight: 200;
}

.logocontainer h1 span {
    font-weight: 800;
}

nav ul {
    float: right;
    height: 100%;
}

nav ul li {
    display: table;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0 20px;
}

nav ul li a {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 100%;
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.innerheader li:last-child {
    padding-right: 0;
}

.checkbtn {
    font-size: 30px;
    color: white;
    float: right;
    line-height: 80px;
    margin-right: 40px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none;
}

#check {
    display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 952px) {
    nav ul li a {
        font-size: 16px;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 858px) {
    .checkbtn {
        display: block;
    }
    nav ul {
        position: fixed;
        width: 100%;
        background: #2c3e50;
        top: 80px;
        left: -100%;
        text-align: center;
        overflow-y: scroll;
    }
    nav ul li {
        display: block;
        line-height: 30px;
        float: none;
    }
    nav ul li a {
        font-size: 20px;
    }
    a:hover,
    a.active {
        background: none;
        color: #0082e6;
    }
    #check:checked~ul {
        left: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Sunrise Brewing Co</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,800" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/d08e6189b7.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <nav>
        <div class="innerheader">
            <input type="checkbox" id="check">
            <label for="check" class="checkbtn">
                <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
            </label>
            <div class="logocontainer">
                <h1><span>SUNRISE</span><br>BREWING</h1>
            </div>
            <ul>
                <li><a class="active" href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Feedback</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your responsive add this media

```
@media only screen and (max-width:875px)
{
  height:auto;
}
```

It's because you have a `height:100%` define in your css that's why your menu list have too much spacing. Or remove `height:100%` in your styling.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```css
nav ul li {
    display: table;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0 20px;
}
```

to:

```css
nav ul li {
    display: table;
    float: left;
    padding: 0 20px;
}
```